# WPF DataGrid is not showing my data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-access, wpfdatagrid

Here is my method to attempt to bind to the DataGrid and it's blank

```
private void getDataFromAccess()
{
    using (OleDbConnection sqlConn = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        sqlConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        string queryString = "SELECT SignIn.VisitorFirstName, SignIn.VisitorLastName, SignIn.SignInDateTime FROM UserList INNER JOIN SignIn ON UserList.POid = SignIn.AssignedPO WHERE (((UserList.FirstName)='First') AND ((UserList.LastName)='Last')) AND SignIn.Complete=False ORDER BY SignIn.SignInDateTime DESC";
        sqlConn.Open();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, sqlConn);

        a.Fill(table);                
    }
}
```

This is my Console code to see if I was able to access the data. It spits the data to the colsole

```
private void testDB()
{
    string connectionString =
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        @"Data Source=R:\\Data\backend.accdb;" +
        @"User Id=;Password=;";

    string queryString = "SELECT SignIn.VisitorFirstName, SignIn.VisitorLastName, SignIn.SignInDateTime FROM UserList INNER JOIN SignIn ON UserList.POid = SignIn.AssignedPO WHERE (((UserList.FirstName)='Sophia') AND ((UserList.LastName)='Peele')) AND SignIn.Complete=False ORDER BY SignIn.SignInDateTime DESC";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() + " " + reader[1].ToString());
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have these private "global to class" variables

```
private String currentUserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
private String firstName, lastName;
private int lastMinute = 1;
private String connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"Data Source=R:\\KIOSK\\ProbationSignIn_be.accdb;" + @"User Id=;Password=;";
private DataTable table;
private OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter;
```

I am using WPF and Access2013 and DataGrid. If there is a better way, please let me know

The goal of the project is to

1. Monitor the table for new visitors that came to visit a particular person
2. Update the record once the person has finished "seeing" the visitor.

Comment: How to pass the DataTable to the dataGrid ? as dataContext or ItemsSource .?

Comment: Which way do you recommend @Med.Amine.Touil ?

Comment: If you are the mvvm design pattern use the datacontext

Comment: Oh I have no idea what MVVM is. (I know what its an acronym for). I use MVC

Comment: Mvc in wpf .!!!!! No waaaay broo

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil how would you solve it?